# Can a non-thin-blood vampire learn thin-blood alchemy?

Tags: character-creation, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e, thin-blood-alchemy

I'm preparing a Vampire the Masquerade v5 campaign, and I'm trying to plan for some questions my players might ask me. One question I have is:

Can a non-thin-blood vampire learn thin-blood alchemy? (And a followup question: Can a thin-blood that didn't learn thin-blood alchemy at character creation learn it later?)

As I read it, it looks like the answer is yes.

> **Thin-blood Alchemist:** The Duskborn change as they feed. Thin-Blood Alchemy is the mastery of this process. Whether it is spontaneous or **a skill learned by comparing notes with other bloodcookers**, you have gained one dot and one formula (p. 282) in Thin-blood Alchemy. You can purchase additional dots and formulae through experience as usual.

But I want to be sure, so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Alchemy requires the weak pseudo-Vitae of thinbloods to have any effect; full vampires can't use it. Mechanically, thin-blood merits aren't available to full vampires.

> These Merits […] only apply to thin-blood characters.

(p182)

For your second question, yes, they can buy Alchemy dots after character creation:

> Thin-bloods […] can also learn Thin-Blood Alchemy through a Merit **or experience**.

(p142, emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

No. The section you have quoted offers reasons why your character might have acquired the Thin-blood Alchemy merit, but that merit is not available to characters of 13th generation or above.